# How do I write a pseudocode that identifies the applicants that qualify for admission and outputs their names, student numbers and modes of study

Tags: pseudocode

so I'm a math major who has received an assignment regarding pseudocode. Below is what the assignment requires of me:

To qualify for admission, an applicant should have at least 25 points, minimum of B symbol in Mathematics and a Minimum of E symbol in English. If an applicant has a C symbol in Mathematics, then the applicant must write and pass an entrance test to be considered for admission. There are three modes of study: The full-time mode, the part-time mode and the Distance mode. Applicants can choose which mode they want provided there is space in that mode. Each of the full time and part-time modes cannot accommodate more than 30 admitted students. After these two modes are full, every other qualified applicant is admitted in the Distance mode. The admission exercise is first come first served. There are 450 applicants.

**Write pseudocode that identifies the applicants that qualify for admission and outputs their names, students numbers and modes of study.** Use a For-loop/do while-loop/ do until loop only (I  understand this part to mean I can use only those loop structures). You must write only one pseudocode that caters for all modes

So here is my code:

Let M=math, E=english,i=counter,x=number of qualified students, FM=full time, PM=part time, D= distance, N=name of the applicant, SN=student number, P=points, y= students who have a C symbol in math, EX= entrance exam grade, z= number of total students, mo=mode of study

```
Start
i=0
y=0
x=0
z=0
FM=0
PM=0
D=0
For i 1 to 450
Enter N,SN,P,M,Eng
if(P>=25) AND (M>=B AND Eng>=E)
then
x= x+1
else
If (P>=25) AND (M=C AND Eng>=E)
then
y=y+1
End if
End if
i=i+1
End for
While EX != A
Enter EX, SN, N
If (EX>=50)
then
Display “student admitted”
until EX=A
Endwhile
z=x+y
While (z !=A)
Enter mo
    If (mo=FM)
    then
        FM=FM+1
    If (FM>30)
    then
        D=D+1
    Else
    If (mo=PM)
    then
        PM=PM+1
    if(PM>30)
    then
        D=D+1
if(mo=D)
then
D=D+1
Endif
Endif
Endif
Endif
Endif
Endwhile
End
```

Comment: So what’s your actual question…?

Comment: This is supposed to be a thought exercise, but if you have a specific problem the community may be able to help.

Comment: My actual question is, how do I add a bunch of pseudocode into my code that stores the applicants who have been deemed eligible through the various criteria and displays their  names, student numbers and modes of study at the end?